# How to convert a generic List<T> to an Interface based List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface, type-conversion

I am sure I am missing something simple, however I am trying to convert a strongly typed list of objects that all implement an interface in to a list of that interface type.

Below is a sample to demonstrate the error:

```
public void ExampleCode(){
    List<Cube> cubes = new List<Cube>();
    List<Shape> allShapes;
    allShapes = cubes;//Syntax Error
    allShapes = (List<Shape>)cubes;//Syntax Error  
}

public class Cube : Shape
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Sides { get; set; }
}

public interface Shape
{
  int ID { get; set; }
  int Sides { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: NB: The code in the question is phrased as a cast (i.e. different view of the same object). The different work arounds given below copy the list - a new list is created and each Shape element added to the new list - giving a different object, not a different view on the same object.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of casting like that, try:

```
allShapes = cubes.Cast<Shape>().ToList();
```

You need .NET 3.5 for this.  I believe the Cast extension method can be found in System.Linq.

Comment: Note, this copies the list (albeit if it contains references the references and not the objects will be copied). This is not the same as casting the list object itself.

Comment: This is as close as you can get in .NET 3.5. There's no way to cast the list object as asked.

Answer (score 6):

You can't. Because `List<T>` and `ILIst<T>` to only support invariant type parameters. This is down to `T` being both use for input and output parameters (e.g. return values). Otherwise you can break the type safety.

Other interfaces (e.g. `IEntumerable<T>`) do allow some variance.

See Eric Lippert's blog "[Fabulous Adventures In Coding](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/default.aspx)" for discussion of contra- and co-variance. Specifically the "[Covariance and Contravariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/tags/Covariance+and+Contravariance/default.aspx)" tag.

Edit, just added to the "C# Frequently Asked Questions" blog: [Covariance and Contravariance FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

What you are referring to is called generic covariance and is not supported by c# 3. It is, however, supported by c# 4 (.NET 4 / VS 2010) and you can read more about it here:

> [Variance in Generic Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233059(VS.100,lightweight).aspx)

Having said that, `IList<T>` is not covariant (because it both accepts and exposes `T`). `IEnumerable<T>`, on the other hand, is covariant (because it doesn't accept `T`).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this since by casting this way you can potentially lose all type safety. For instnce, casting `List<Shape>` to `List<object>` will result in that objects of *any* type can be added to the list, which will be downright inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
allShapes = cubes.ConvertAll(x => (Shape)x);
```

Or if you are doing this in .NET 2.0:

```
allShapes = cubes.ConvertAll<Shape>(delegate(Cube c){
    return (Shape)c;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast between lists of types, even if the types themselves are convertible. You will need to create a new list and populate it, either by iterating the original list or by using ConvertAll. See http://www.dev102.com/2008/05/15/how-to-convert-listt1-to-listt2/ for sample code.

Answer (score 0):

This works if you define  allShapes as IEnumerable

In C# 4.0  you may simply assign allshapes=cubes

For C# 3.5 you could use  allShapes = cubes.Select(c=>((Shape)c));

But in any case you need to use IEnumerable instead of List